# Javascript animate element movement at a variable angle and speed?

Tags: javascript, animation, math

I was wondering how to go about calculating the new X, Y position of an element I am trying to animate with JavaScripts setInterval.  I want to move the element at a certain angle and pixels per second, calculating a new X,Y for the element during each frame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8tcgezj/

Click on the ball, and check out the throwBall function in my code.  I have it hardcoded too move the ball at a 90 degree angle at a speed of 1 pixel per frame @ 60 FPS, so 60 pixels per second.  But what If I want to move the ball at a 62 degree angle at a speed of 100 pixels per second?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

    var ball;
    var ballX = 100;
    var ballY = 100;
    var ballClicked = false;

    window.onload = function() {

        ball = document.createElement("div");
        ball.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        ball.style.border = "2px solid black";
        ball.style.width = "50px";
        ball.style.height = "50px";
        ball.style.position = "absolute";
        ball.style.left = ballX + "px";
        ball.style.top = ballY + "px";
        ball.style.borderRadius = "50%";
        ball.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) { onBallMouseDown(e); }, false);
        ball.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e) { onBallMouseUp(e); }, false);
        ball.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) { onBallMouseDown(e); }, false);
        ball.addEventListener('touchend',function(e) { onBallMouseUp(e); }, false);
        document.body.appendChild(ball);

        document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e) { onMouseMove(e); }, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) { onTouchMove(e); }, false);

    };

    function onMouseMove(e) {

        if (ballClicked == true) {
            ballX = e.pageX - 25;
            ballY = e.pageY - 25;
            ball.style.left = ballX + "px";
            ball.style.top = ballY + "px";
        }

    };

    function onTouchMove(e) {

        if (ballClicked == true) {
            ballX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - 25;
            ballY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - 25;
            ball.style.left = ballX + "px";
            ball.style.top = ballY + "px";
        }

    };

    function onBallMouseDown(e) {

        ballClicked = true;

    };

    function onBallMouseUp(e) {

        ballClicked = false;

        //When the ball is released, it will be thrown at an angle relative to it's original position when it is thrown..  
        //For testing purposes, let's throw a the ball at 90 degrees with a speed of 60 pixels per second.
        throwBall(60,50);

    };

    function throwBall(angle, speed) {

        var animationComplete = false;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {

                //How do I Calculate the new X and Y position for the ball during each frame, based on the angle and speed which it was thrown?

                //This will move the ball at a 90 degree angle (north) at a speed of 1 pixel per frame.
                ballX = ballX + 0;
                ballY = ballY - 1;

                ball.style.left = ballX + "px";
                ball.style.top = ballY + "px";

                if (animationComplete == true) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    console.log("ball throw animation complete.");
                }

        }, 1000 / 60);

    };

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you don't use jQuery? It can reduce your code.

Comment: Hi Vipul I actually am using jQuery mobiel just not in the code I posted.  But I really want to accomplish this in pure Js just to learn how to do things the hard way, so then I can appreciate jQuery even more when I move on to that fully.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to figure the x and y component of the velocity in pixels per frame:
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8kkv9973/2/

I don't know how familiar you are with the math required, but let me know if you have any questions about it.

You should definitely do some research into javascript animation though.

Here's the updated function:

```
function throwBall(angle, speed) {

    var animationComplete = false;

    //put the angle in radians
    var rads = angle * Math.PI / 180;

    //calculate the x and y components of the velocity in pixels per frame
    //speed is in pixels per second, so divide by 60 to get pixels per frame
    var vx = Math.cos(rads)*speed/60;
    var vy = Math.sin(rads)*speed/60;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        //How do I Calculate the new X and Y position for the ball during each frame, based on the angle and speed which it was thrown?

        ballX = ballX + vx;
        ballY = ballY - vy;

        ball.style.left = ballX + "px";
        ball.style.top = ballY + "px";

        if (animationComplete == true) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("ball throw animation complete.");
        }

    }, 1000 / 60);

};
```

Comment: hey just wanted to say thanks, this was a very helpful answer so I checkmarked it...really appreciate it :)  By the way I might message you in the future.